# U.N. FAO API - How do I do a POST data request via JS with this API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, post

I am trying to do a POST request (via JavaScript AJAX) to the United Nations Food and Agriculture Organization (U.N. FAO) API to get some data points.  While I have successfully completed GET requests to this API with no problem, the POST requests continuously fail.  I've done this type of request with many other APIs, but this one I can't figure out.

My code and URLs related to the API are below.

Can anyone please help me successfully complete a POST data request to this FAO API?  Either modifying my code or creating your own example code would be fine.

The API endpoint is here:
http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/en/data/

The API's technical description is here:
http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/

The 'Example Page' for the API is here:
http://faostat.github.io/faostat-api/

The 'Showcase Page' for the API is here:
http://fenixapps.fao.org/repository/api/

My code -- a working GET request + non-working POST request -- is below.
You can cut-and-paste it into a text editor and it will work as an HTML file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function test() {
            // (1) GET requests work fine.
            // Based on example by FAOSTAT (http://faostat.github.io/faostat-api/)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:  'http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/en/classifications/QC',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log("metadata GET response:");
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });

            // (2) POST requests do NOT work with my code.
            // Originally based on example by FAOSTAT (http://faostat.github.io/faostat-api/)
            // Modified per API description at: http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/
            $.ajax({
                url:  "http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/en/data/",
                traditional: true,
                data: {
                    "datasource": "production", //test
                    "output_type": "objects", //arrays
                    "api_key": "n.a.",
                    "client_key": "n.a.",
                    "lang": "en",
                    //"domain_code":"QC", //domain_code (from example page - http://faostat.github.io/faostat-api/) replaced by domain_codes?
                    "domain_codes": ["'QC'"],
                    //"thousand_separator": ",", //not mentioned at http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/, only on example page.
                    //"decimal_separator": ".", //not mentioned at http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/, only on example page.
                    "decimal_places": "2",
                    "List1Codes": ["'33'"],
                    "List2Codes": ["'2510'"],
                    "List3Codes": ["'15'"],
                    "List4Codes": ["'2007'","'2008'","'2009'","'2010'","'2011'","'2012'","'2013'","'2014'"],
                    "List5Codes": null,
                    "List6Codes": null,
                    "List7Codes": null,
                    "null_values": true,
                    //"group_by"
                    //"order_by"
                    //"operator"
                    "page_size":"100",
                    "limit": "10",
                    "page_number":1
                    //"show_codes"
                    //"show_flags"
                    //"show_unit"
                },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log("data POST response:");
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='test();'>
    <div id='out'></div>
</body>
```

**---UPDATE---**

I have tried changing the `data` section within `$.ajax()` so that the url created exactly matches the format of that of the cURL example from the FAO 'Example' page (http://faostat.github.io/faostat-api/).  However, this has not altered the API's response.  My updated code is included below -- the new `console.log(urlPlusData);` line I believe should reflect the full url that the code is generating for the POST.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function test() {
            // (1) GET requests work fine.
            // Based on example by FAOSTAT (http://faostat.github.io/faostat-api/)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:  'http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/en/classifications/QC',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log("metadata GET response:");
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });

            // (2) POST requests do NOT work with my code.
            // Originally based on example by FAOSTAT (http://faostat.github.io/faostat-api/)
            // Modified per API description at: http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/
            $.ajax({
                url:  "http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/en/data",
                traditional: true,
                data: {
                    "datasource": "production", //test
                    "output_type": "objects", //arrays
                    "api_key": "n.a.",
                    "client_key": "n.a.",
                    "lang": "en",
                    //"domain_code":"QC", //domain_code (from example page) replaced by domain_codes?
                    "domain_codes": ["QC"],
                    //"thousand_separator": ",", //not mentioned at http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/, only on example page.
                    //"decimal_separator": ".", //not mentioned at http://fenixapps2.fao.org/api/v1.0/, only on example page.
                    "decimal_places": "2",
                    "List1Codes": ["33"],
                    "List2Codes": ["2510"],
                    "List3Codes": ["15"],
                    "List4Codes": ["2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012"],
                    "List5Codes": ["null"],
                    "List6Codes": ["null"],
                    "List7Codes": ["null"],
                    "null_values": true,
                    //"group_by"
                    //"order_by"
                    //"operator"
                    "page_size":"100",
                    "limit": "10",
                    "page_number":"1"
                    //"show_codes"
                    //"show_flags"
                    //"show_unit"
                },
                beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                    urlPlusData = settings.url + "?" + settings.data;
                },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log("data POST response:");
                    console.log(urlPlusData);
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='test();'>
    <div id='out'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: you format is off. don't send json, send repetitive params to encode an array. ex: `List1Codes=["'2'","'8'"]` should be the cleaner `&List1Codes=2&List1Codes=8`; see example

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure I understand "don't send json"?  If I am using $.ajax(), then aren't I already necessarily using JSON?  Also, I should mention that I have played around with formatting the quotation marks many different ways, with no success.

Comment: it needs to ultimatly hit the wire looking the same as the curl example; i'm not a jq expert, and it looks like it's trying to be "smart", but it's easy using vanilla since you just feed it the same thing as curl, or with FormData if you want to pass it structured objects without building up the string requestbody yourself.

Comment: @dandavis I tried changing the `data` section of `$.ajax()` so that the URL being generated should exactly match the format of what the 'example page' shows for its cURL example (pls see code in 'UPDATE' section).  However, I am still getting the same 'empty' response, containing no data points.